Can't access AWS system manager paramter store in lambda in a vpc with sst
I have a vpc with 1 subnet, 1 security groupe and 2 VPC endpoints (1 for lambda and 1 secret manager (I just say that it's useless because I use system manager not secret manager))
For some reason, my lambda is not able to access system manager parameter store secrets
Since I am using SST the only real way that I found in the doc is to define the secret in your stack and get your env at runtime
When I get the secret in my lambda I get a timeout
{
  "errorMessage": "2024-08-17T21:10:15.543Z 6c840282-14d7-4dde-9001-fc81a2834a21 Task timed out after 5.01 seconds"
}

MyStack.ts
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import { Config, Function, StackContext } from 'sst/constructs';

export function MyStack({ stack }: StackContext) {
  const secrets = {
    MONGODB_PROD_URL: new Config.Secret(stack, 'MONGODB_PROD_URL'),
  };
  const securityGroup = ec2.SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(stack, 'default', 'sg-XXXXXX');
  const subnet = ec2.Subnet.fromSubnetId(stack, 'my-subnet', 'subnet-XXXXXX');

  const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(stack, 'db-vpc', {
    vpcId: 'vpc-XXXXXX',
  });

  const myLambda = new Function(stack, 'hello-function', {
    handler: 'src/functions/hello/handler.main',
    runtime: 'nodejs20.x',
    bind: [secrets.MONGODB_PROD_URL],
    vpc,
    vpcSubnets: {
      subnets: [subnet],
    },
    securityGroups: [securityGroup],
    timeout: 5,
    memorySize: 2048,
    enableLiveDev: true,
  });

  stack.addOutputs({
    LambdaName: myLambda.functionName,
  });
}

handler.ts
import { APIGatewayProxyEventV2 } from 'aws-lambda';
import { ApiHandler } from 'sst/node/api';
import { Config } from 'sst/node/config';
import { logger } from '../../helpers/logger';

export const main = ApiHandler(async (_event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2) => {
  logger.info('Hello');
  logger.info({ MONGODB_PROD_URL: Config.MONGODB_PROD_URL.toString() }); // <-- comment this line and it works again

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: `Hello world. The time is ${new Date().toISOString()}`,
  };
});


Perhaps SST is wanting to access resources on the Internet? It is likely that your AWS Lambda function has no Internet access.

I have no NAT gateway configured if this is the question but why would I need internet to get a parameter store secret (I just realised the my secret manager endpoint is useless because I use system manager not secret) ?

I'm not sure you do require it. That's why I asked it as a question.

I found the solution it was the wrong endpoint I needed ssm endpoint not secret manager my bad
Just tested it now it works !

Excellent! If you think future readers will benefit from your Question, then please add your own Answer. However, if it was due to a typo or a mistake, feel free to Delete your Question.

If you use SST secrets and your lambda is in a VPC you need to add a VPC endpoints for ssm with the service com.amazonaws.eu-west-3.ssm (because SST secrets are stored in System manager parameter store)
More infos : Accessing Parameter Store from VPC / Lambda

You don't ordinarily need a VPC endpoint to the Lambda service in order to access secrets.

True I did the change
